# Java Swing - How to get the value of text in a TextField from another class

Tags: java, swing, scope, jtextfield

Okay, beginner Java coder here. 
I'm trying to make a multi-purpose math utility application with Java Swing. One of the things I want it to do is be able to solve basic logarithms. I have the logic all down, but I'm having trouble with the outputting itself. I have a class (named "LogTab") and within it is a nested static class (named "LogPanel") for the actual input area. The button is outside the LogPanel class, and when I press it I want it to be able to take the values of the TextFields inside the LogTab (named "logBase" and "logNum"), calculate them, and send them to an output class. I have everything fine and working except for **the part where I take the values from the TextFields**.

Here's my code.

```
public class LogTab extends JPanel {

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
static class LogInput extends JComponent {

    public LogInput() {
        JComponent logInputPanel = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JTextField logLbl = new JTextField();
        logLbl.setText("Log");
        logLbl.setEditable(false);
        JTextField logBase = new JTextField(1);
        JTextField logNum = new JTextField(5);

        GridBagConstraints lgc = new GridBagConstraints();

        lgc.weightx = 0.5;
        lgc.weighty = 0.5;

        lgc.gridx = 0;
        lgc.gridy = 0;
        add(logLbl,lgc);

        lgc.gridx = 1;
        lgc.gridy = 1;
        add(logBase,lgc);

        lgc.gridx = 2;
        lgc.gridy = 0;
        add(logNum,lgc);
    }
}

public LogTab() {
    // Set Layout
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    // Create components
    JLabel promptLabel = new JLabel("Enter Logarithm: ");
    JButton solveButton = new JButton("Solve");
    final LogInput logInput = new LogInput();
    solveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double base = Double.valueOf(logInput.logBase.getText());
                double num = Double.valueOf(logInput.logNum.getText());
                OutputPanel.outputField.setText(String.valueOf(solve(base,num)));
            } finally {
            }

        }

    });



    // Code that adds the components, bla bla bla




}

public double solve(double base, double num) {
    return (Math.log(base)/Math.log(num));
}
}
```

When I try to compile this (through Eclipse, by the way), I get an error saying that "logBase/logNum can not be resolved or is not a field". How would I change this so that my ActionListener can get the text from the TextFields?

Thanks

P.S. This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so if I messed something up, tell me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `logBase` and `logNum` instance fields...

```
static class LogInput extends JComponent {

    private JTextField logBase;
    private JTextField logNum;

    public LogInput() {
        JComponent logInputPanel = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JLabel logLbl = new JLabel("Log");
        logBase = new JTextField(1);
        logNum = new JTextField(5);
```

Now add some getters...

```
public double getBase() {
    String text = logBase.getText();
    if (text.trim().isEmpty()) {
        text = "0";
    }
    return Double.parseDouble(text);
}

public double getNumber() {
    String text = logNum.getText();
    if (text.trim().isEmpty()) {
        text = "0";
    }
    return Double.parseDouble(text);
}
```

Now you can access the values of `logBase` and `logNum` from any instance of `LogInput`

About this point, I'm thinking that either a `JSpinner` or `JTextField` would be a better idea, as they have the ability to validate the input themselves.  See [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more details

Comment: I see what you meant with the instance fields, but when I run the getters I come up with a NullPointerException. Specifically, at the line `String text = logBase.getText();`. This might be an issue with some other part of the code, I don't know.

Comment: This is probably because you've redeclared the textfields in the construct, see how my example looks

Comment: There we go! Solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the scope of `logBase` and `logNum` is limited only to the constructor, and therefore is not accessible by other methods.

Make `logBase` and `logNum` fields of `LogInput`:

```
static class LogInput extends JComponent {
    JTextField logBase, logNum;
```

And in the constructor, remove the `JTextField` identifier:

```
logBase = new JTextField(1);
logNum = new JTextField(5);
```