# How to setText for a text Field in a class from another class

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent

I want to access JTextField of a class from another class , From the new class i want to setText to the textField.

from class patient_details i want to access the JTextField present in class     Admission_screen. This is code which i used in patient_details class to add text in text field present in admission_screen class.

```
 Admission_screen admit=new Admission_screen();
                 admit.t2.setText("xxx");
```

t2 is the textfiels present in admission_screen class.

this is not working help me with your suggestions

Comment: Something like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653892/java-swing-how-to-get-the-value-of-text-in-a-textfield-from-another-class/28654237?noredirect=1#comment45627572_28654237)?

Comment: 1) *"I want to access JTextBox.."*  There's no such class in the J2SE.  2) *"help me with ur suggestions"*  I suggest you spell words like 'your' properly and check class names before posting.

Comment: sry .... its Textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to `Admission_screen`:

```
public void setT2Text(String text){
    t2.setText(text);
}
```

Call it using the admit object you created. Like so:
`admit.setT2Text("txt");`

Comment: your right @Dando18 .......... but I made mistake by creating two objects for one class .... your answer was helpful for me find my mistake ...thank you